# Spelling error on the moderator self-nomination page

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

There is a spelling error in the aside on the moderator self-nomination page on Stack Overflow. Please change "exibit" to "exhibit."

> **Describe why you would make a good moderator**
>
> Good moderators often:
>
> [...]
>
> ► **exibit** those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation

Comment: What about xibit? Then we can all make updog jokes!

Comment: Spelling/grammar errors = free rep! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will go out with the next build.